# Reverse spread using gather

Tags: r, dplyr

We have a rating matrix:

```
df <- data.frame(Customer.ID=c("c1",'c1','c1','c2','c2','c3'),
             Movie.ID=c("m1", "m3", "m5", "m1", "m5", "m7"),
             Rating=c(1,2,1,3,3,1))
df
  Customer.ID Movie.ID Rating
1          c1       m1      1
2          c1       m3      2
3          c1       m5      1
4          c2       m1      3
5          c2       m5      3
6          c3       m7      1
```

When I spread and change row names like this:

```
df1 <- df %>% spread(key = 'Movie.ID', value = 'Rating')
df1 <- data.frame(df1, row.names = 'Customer.ID')
```

I get:

```
> df1
   m1 m3 m5 m7
c1  1  2  1 NA
c2  3 NA  3 NA
c3 NA NA NA  1
```

I want to make `df1` look like `df` again.

I have tried:

```
df2 <-setDT(df1, keep.rownames = TRUE)[]
df2 <- gather(df2, Video.ID, Rating, 2:4)
```

But it returns me:

```
> df2
  rn m7 Video.ID Rating
1 c1 NA       m1      1
2 c2 NA       m1      3
3 c3  1       m1     NA
4 c1 NA       m3      2
5 c2 NA       m3     NA
6 c3  1       m3     NA
7 c1 NA       m5      1
8 c2 NA       m5      3
9 c3  1       m5     NA
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? seems like you are trying to solve a problem and assuming this is the solution; it's probably not

Comment: I need to spread my real dataset (df) in order to make some visuals and some data cleaning. And I need to bring it back to the initial format after. But I fail to use gather I gues..

Comment: The visuals and data cleaning will almost certainly work better in the long (gathered) format

Comment: That is right. But since I am a beginner in R, I can only remove customers who haven't bought at least x amount of items easily in wide format by using rowSums, or remove items that haven't been watched by y amount of user by using colSums..
Would be nice for me to understand how to do this in long format as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am not certain why you are doing this (see @Jack Brookes comment), you can do this pretty readily with `dplyr` functions:

```
df1 %>% 
  rownames_to_column('Customer.ID') %>% 
  gather(m1:m7, key = 'Movie.ID', value = 'Rating') %>% 
  filter(!is.na(Rating))
```

Which gives us:

```
  Customer.ID Movie.ID Rating
1          c1       m1      1
2          c2       m1      3
3          c1       m3      2
4          c1       m5      1
5          c2       m5      3
6          c3       m7      1
```